# Need Help With Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks

I've just run Intrument's Memory Leaks Tool for my app and am getting the following errors:

[image]

Here is the method it is referring to:

Specficlaly at this line: `NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@", selectedExerciseName]]`

```
- (void)createSession
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponentsForToday = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:self.picker.date];
    [dateComponentsForToday setHour:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setMinute:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setSecond:0];
    NSDate *targetDateBegins = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponentsForToday]; 
    NSDate *targetDateEnds = [targetDateBegins dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24 - 1)];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@)", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

    if ([results count])
    {
        session = (Session *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Already have session for date: %@", session.timeStamp);
    }
    else
    {
        session = (Session *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        session.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
        NSLog(@"New session for date: %@", session.timeStamp);
    }

    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@", selectedExerciseName]];
    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"exercise does not already exist");
        self.exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        self.exercise.name = selectedExerciseName;
        [session addExercisesObject:exercise];
        NSLog(@"exercise name: %@", exercise.name);
        NSLog(@"exercises in session:  %@",session.exercises);
    }

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);

    [fetchRequest release];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession. have you release this object ?

Comment: @singhSan filteredExercisesFromSession is on autorelease already.

Comment: I've actually restructured this code a little bit so you can ignore the question for now.  My newer code (although not yet working) can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195311/need-help-to-modify-my-code-slightly-nsobject.

Comment: Let me tell you, the cause of the leak is not always what instruments tell you. It can be that the object that creates object with createSession method leaks or you're releasing explicitly object that's on autorelease. Run static analyzer before running Instruments to look for leaks. Doing so can save you alot of trouble sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has `self.exercise =` which takes ownership so make sure in the dealloc you release the member variable that backs the exercise property.

Comment: should I remove self.exercise and replace it with just exercise?

Comment: No that won't solve the problem. self.exercise (if it's a retain property) takes ownership of an autoreleased object. Which is what you want. If you replaced self.exercise with exercise you would need to retain the autoreleased object. In both cases since you take ownership you need to relinquish ownership at some point. And since it is a property typically you do this in the dealloc.